# Limit dropdown max-height to screen height in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, overflow

I have an HTML page that needs to show a lot of content in dropdowns in the navbar on top which leads some of the dropdowns to exceed the screen height when opening them. I use Bootstrap 3 and have my own dropdowns created using unordered list (`<ul>`) tags.

If I apply the following CSS than this resolves the issue and also gets me a vertical scrollbar which is what I want in that case. My only problem here is that the max-height is a fixed value. Note: I need to be able to support IE8 and IE9.

Is there a way to use CSS or jQuery to set this to the screen height (or a bit less) so that the max-height adjusts if the screen height changes, esp. to support smaller screens?

My CSS:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-height:300px; overflow:auto">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will set the list's height so as not to overflow the screen.
Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('ul').css('max-height', ($(window).height() - $('ul').offset().top) + 'px');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! How would I make this auto-update when the screen-height changes. Is there a way to recalculate this on screen height change ?

Comment: Perfect - this is great. Thanks a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)